# How to pass Bitmap between two fragment ? ( I am using Android Navigation Component )

Tags: android, bitmap, uri, android-bitmap, android-navigation

I am building a photo editor . For painting , adjusting , cropping etc. i created fragments . i face passing bitmap and Uri i face problems which are describe below .

Firstly , I applied two approches one

1. first approche I pass a object which is which is `CommonParcelData`

`@Parcelize data class CommonParcelData( val uri:Uri?=null,val bitmap: Bitmap?=null, val availableData: ActiveNavArgsData, var isResize:Boolean=false ): Parcelable`

**problem** is when I pass the data using `CommonParcelData` data class then for i is showing **error** like `java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 17488344 bytes` and `JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!`  because i passed bitmap object . then I choose my second approche .

2. Second Approch is I take the **edited bitmap** and  android convert into **uri** and save inside cache directory and send the **uri** to the destination/other fragment but **problem this approch is it is very slow for fragment transtion** . For simplify I created a which convert ***save the bitmap into storage and get uri*** that class is SaveBitmapInStorage

   class SaveBitmapInStorage(private val context: Context) {

   ```
    companion object {
        private val TAG = SaveBitmapInStorage::class.java.simpleName
    }

    var compressionQuality = 100
        set(value) {
            if (value in 0..100) {
                field = value
            } else {
                throw Exception("compressionQuality value must be between 0 to 100")
            }
        }

    private var imgExtension = ImgExtension.PNG.name.lowercase()

    fun changeImgExtension(imgType: ImgExtension) {
        imgExtension = imgType.name.lowercase()
    }

    private val dirName = context.getString(R.string.app_name)

    private val appName = dirName



    private val folder =
        File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.parentFile?.parentFile?.parentFile?.parentFile?.path + File.separator + appName)


    /** It must be execute on background thread */
    fun save(bitmap: Bitmap, isSaveInCacheDir: Boolean = false): Uri {
        if (!folder.isDirectory) {
            folder.mkdir()
            Log.d(TAG, " file created :-> $folder")
        }


        val imgFile = if (isSaveInCacheDir) File(context.cacheDir, getCacheImgFile)
        else File(folder, "$appName${System.currentTimeMillis()}.$imgExtension")


        try {

            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(imgFile)

            checkImgFormat(bitmap, fileOutputStream)

            fileOutputStream.apply {
                flush();
                close()
            }


        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

        }

        return Uri.fromFile(imgFile)


    }


    private fun checkImgFormat(bitmap: Bitmap, fos: FileOutputStream) {
        when (imgExtension) {
            ImgExtension.PNG.name.lowercase() -> {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, compressionQuality, fos)
            }

            ImgExtension.JPG.name.lowercase() -> {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressionQuality, fos)
            }


        }

    }


    private val getCacheImgFile = "${context.getString(R.string.cache_img_name)}.$imgExtension"

    /** This should be in background thread ... */
    fun savePhotoInCacheDir(bitmap: Bitmap): Uri {

        return save(bitmap, true)

    }
   ```

   }

**In ViewModel**

```
fun savePhotoInCacheStorage(result: (resultUri: Uri) -> Unit) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val uri = saveBitmapInStorage.savePhotoInCacheDir(_imgSrc.value!!)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                result(uri)
            }
        }

    }
```

**In UI means in Fragment**

```
binding.editorIncludeId.crop.setOnClickListener {

            mainEditViewModel.savePhotoInCacheStorage {
                val data =CommonParcelData(it,availableData = ActiveNavArgsData.URI)
                val action = MainEditScreenFragmentDirections
                    .mainEditScreenFragmentToCropFragment(data)

                findNavController().navigate(action,getSharedElementExtra())
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this way to pass Bitmap. First convert the Bitmap into a Byte array and then encode that Byte array to a String Like this,

```
 val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream)
    val b = outputStream.toByteArray()
val encodedBitmap = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

And then you can pass it as an Intent extra.

To decode the String back into a Bitmap you can do this way,

```
val b = Base64.decode(previouslyEncodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT)
val bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length)
```

Where `previousEncodedImage` is the string value you will retrieve from your Intent.

Comment: yup it works  . But my problem is not resolve because which I described in my second approch , means it will resolve the `JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!`  problem but transaction time between two fragment is slow .